# Elastic Load Balancing report Out of Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling

I am using the loadbalancing and autoscaling feature on aws.

The load balancer marks the instance "out of service". However, the instance (i-xxxx) is running fine and status checks that report "Insufficient Data".

But I unable to connect SSH connection to the server knowing that the instance is changing when scaling up or down.

Error logs : -

```
Cause: At 2015-05-07T05:54:27Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.
Cause: At 2015-05-07T03:04:13Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a EC2 instance status checks failure.
```

Comment: Can you review this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html and edit your post with more details if you're still having issues?

Comment: If your instance is not getting in service that means that your health check is failing. How is your health check configured and has your application really been bootstrapped and launched correctly?